# PHP echo the lowest value from a list of dynamically generated array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm using a Wordpress shopping theme and it displays the products details (price, colors etc) as json scripts, however I need to display at least the price as text. The developer was not very helpful and my php knowledge is limited to none, so I'm hoping this will be an easy/fast fix for someone here.
This is the part of the script that generates the json:

```
if(is_array($product['skuAttr'])) {
    $str_data['offers'] = [];
    foreach ($product['skuAttr'] as $k => $attr) {
        $str_data['offers'][] = [
            "@type" => "Offer",
            "url" => $this_url . '?sku=' . $k,
            "priceCurrency" => $product['currency'],
            "price" => $attr['_salePrice_nc'],
            "priceValidUntil" => date('Y-m-d',
                strToTime('today + 30 days')
            ),
            "name" => $itemmeta['name'],
            "availability" => $attr['isActivity'] ? "https://schema.org/InStock" : "https://schema.org/OutOfStock",
            "itemCondition" => "https://schema.org/NewCondition"
        ];
        $min_saleprice = min($attr['_salePrice_nc']);  // that's mine

    }
}
```

...and later on:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    <?php echo json_encode($str_data); ?>
</script>
```

The $min_saleprice was my idea that I later echoed and, of course, it broke the site.

```
<?php echo $min_saleprice; ?>  /// not a chance
```

So, how to display the _salePrice_nc later in the document?
Thank you.

If it matters, I am using the latest Wordpress 5.6.1, PHP 7.2, nGinx and I need this to validate the products on Pinterest, whose scraper is not smart enough to get the price from the script, and I think it must find it in page as plain text.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlF6B.png)

Comment: Forgot to say that the json script generates fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made two critical errors:

1. You were looking for the minimal price in the wrong place (you were trying to select the minimial value of a *single* price - it's not an array).
2. You were overwriting the variable in each iteration.

The correct place where you should look for the minimal value is the final array of all offers and it should be done outside the loop. The following code will achieve this:

```php
$min_saleprice = min(array_column($str_data['offers'], 'price'));
```

The `array_column` function extracts all of the `price` values from `$str_data['offers']` and then `min` selects the lowest of them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the lowest value of the price in offers then you can build an array just for that purpose and get the lowest of that.

But you will need to make sure this is outside the loop.

```
if(is_array($product['skuAttr'])) {
    $str_data['offers'] = [];
    $productPrices = [];
    foreach ($product['skuAttr'] as $k => $attr) {
        $productPrices[] = $attr['_salePrice_nc'];
        $str_data['offers'][] = [
            "@type" => "Offer",
            "url" => $this_url . '?sku=' . $k,
            "priceCurrency" => $product['currency'],
            "price" => $attr['_salePrice_nc'],
            "priceValidUntil" => date('Y-m-d',
                strToTime('today + 30 days')
            ),
            "name" => $itemmeta['name'],
            "availability" => $attr['isActivity'] ? "https://schema.org/InStock" : "https://schema.org/OutOfStock",
            "itemCondition" => "https://schema.org/NewCondition"
        ];
    }

    $min_saleprice = min($productPrices);
}
```